In rust, how can I convert between nested enums and strings
I've got some nested enums like below -- the struct variants will only ever contain another enum, never any other data.
pub enum InteractionCode {
    MenuCharacterCreation { action: CharacterCreationAction },

    // this was how i was doing it before, 
    // but it's becoming cumbersome with so many interactions
    // especially with ones in different categories
    // the advantage is I can use Strum
    // MenuCharacterCreation_Open, 
}

#[derive(AsRefStr)]
pub enum CharacterCreationAction {
    Open,
}

The library I'm using needs to generate strings to send to UI components for interactions, and when handling those interactions I need to convert back to enums so I can match appropriately.  So I need to convert this example into something like "MenuCharacterCreation_Open" and back into
MenuCharacterCreation {
  action: CharacterCreationAction::Open
}

I started out just writing a simple as_str and from_str to create hard coded "MenuCharacterCreation_Open" type strings and back using matches, but that is very cumbersome as I add values.
I thought I might be missing some easier way to interrogate the nested enum variants without giant match statements to create the strings.  Or possibly some better technique in general that I'm unaware of.  Is there a crate or a better way to do this?  I looked into strum but it doesn't really deal with nested enums.

I don't know of any premade solutions that do this, but its not too hard to implement this by yourself. I'll assume you have some existing idea for converting your *Action enums to and from strings (whether it be manual implementations or a macro) I'm using derive-more below but see this and this for other options.
If your string format includes a separator like "_" (which you show), then you can easily use .split_once() to get the separate enum strings and just match and sub-parse based on them. To create the string, you can just format it with _ included. Here's how that would look:
use std::fmt::{Display, Error as FmtError, Formatter};
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, derive_more::Display, derive_more::FromStr)]
pub enum CharacterCreationAction {
    Open,
}

#[derive(Debug, derive_more::Display, derive_more::FromStr)]
pub enum InventoryAction {
    Open,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum InteractionCode {
    MenuCharacterCreation { action: CharacterCreationAction },
    MenuInventory { action: InventoryAction },
}

impl Display for InteractionCode {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), FmtError> {
        match self {
            Self::MenuCharacterCreation { action } => write!(f, "MenuCharacterCreation_{}", action),
            Self::MenuInventory { action } => write!(f, "MenuInventory_{}", action),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct InteractionCodeParseError;

impl FromStr for InteractionCode {
    type Err = InteractionCodeParseError;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, InteractionCodeParseError> {
        let (code, action) = s.split_once('_').ok_or(InteractionCodeParseError)?;
        match code {
            "MenuCharacterCreation" => Ok(Self::MenuCharacterCreation {
                action: action.parse().map_err(|_| InteractionCodeParseError)?,
            }),
            "MenuInventory" => Ok(Self::MenuInventory {
                action: action.parse().map_err(|_| InteractionCodeParseError)?,
            }),
            _ => Err(InteractionCodeParseError),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let code1: Result<InteractionCode, _> = "MenuCharacterCreation_Open".parse();
    let code2: Result<InteractionCode, _> = "MenuInventory_Open".parse();
    let code3: Result<InteractionCode, _> = "OtherType_OtherAction".parse();

    dbg!(code1);
    dbg!(code2);
    dbg!(code3);
}

[src/main.rs:53:5] code1 = Ok(
    MenuCharacterCreation {
        action: Open,
    },
)
[src/main.rs:54:5] code2 = Ok(
    MenuInventory {
        action: Open,
    },
)
[src/main.rs:55:5] code3 = Err(
    InteractionCodeParseError,
)

This does still have hard-coded string-values for the outer enum implementations (and thus not automatically follow renaming), but a macro wouldn't be hard to make if it is critical. Error construction can improved.
